# Risk of checking string of URL with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, xss

While surfing throughout the web for different solutions for my website, I always double check for security risks, especially when it's about server globals.

Although I understand the risk of using input data without sanitizing, I'm not sure about using server global vars for simple PHP functions.

I'm using a function to check wether there's a specific string in my URL:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'foo') !== false) :
// do something
endif;
```

Do I have to worry about any XSS or injection fun?

Comment: Unlikely, but yes, you do. It's something that comes with the http headers, so it can be set to whatever the attacker wants. But unless you are passing it to eval or printing it without escaping, you shouldn't be worrying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can stay relaxed.

Some problem can rarely exists if you try to eval the variable as code, but is not your case.

The main security problem of global variables reside in the *year-ago-popular* directive `register_globals` (removed as of PHP 5.4.0): with this option active, all GET and POST variables were converted in global variables (i.e. `$_GET['user']` available as `$user`).

So, calling a url like `http://example.com/index.php?destroyall=1`, if `index.php` is:

```
if( $_GET['areYouSure']==1 )
{
    $destroyall = 1;
}
if( $destroyall )
{
    deleteAllMyFilesNow();
}
```

`deleteAllMyFilesNow()` is performed, even if `areYouSure` is False, because `$_GET[destroyall]` set directly the value of `$destroyall`.

To understand how much the `register_global` was popular, considers that the [PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) reports:

> Perhaps the most controversial change in PHP is when the default value for the PHP directive register_globals went from ON to OFF

Comment: Hey Dude, thanks for your answer and sorry for my late reply. This helped alot!!!